# How can i add new lines when copying to clipboard

Tags: javascript, angular, copy-paste

Im trying to add a button that when clicked it will copy the text inside the div with it adding `/n` to whereever there is a new line. Right now i have it to where its copying everything but its not adding the new lines where is needed. Right the results im getting is this:
Data Sources: ADS-B:  200  MIDB: 150  Twitter: 0 Overlay: overlay1:  url  overkay2: url  overlay3: url KML: kml1:  url  kml2: url  kml3: url Callouts: ADS-B:  200  MIDB: 150  Twitter: 0 LiveFeeds: No LiveFeeds. But I want it to look the same as in the picture.[image]

```js
mport { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'visualization-source-packet-dialog',
  templateUrl: './visualization-source-packet-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./visualization-source-packet-dialog.component.scss']
})
export class VisualizationSourcePacketDialogComponent implements OnInit {
  public sampleSources = ['ADS-B:  200', 'MIDB: 150', 'Twitter: 0'];
  public sampleOverlay = ['overlay1:  url', 'overkay2: url', 'overlay3: url'];
  public sampleKmls = ['kml1:  url', 'kml2: url', 'kml3: url'];
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("hitting")
  }
   
  public copy(text: string) {
    console.log(text)
    const copyText = document.getElementsByClassName("data");

    const dummy = document.createElement("input");
    document.body.appendChild(dummy);
    dummy.setAttribute('value', copyText[0].textContent);
    dummy.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(dummy);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="data">
        <div>
            <h4>Data Sources:</h4>
            <div *ngFor="let source of sampleSources">
                {{ source }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h4>Overlay:</h4>
            <div *ngFor="let source of sampleOverlay">
                {{ source }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h4>KML:</h4>
            <div *ngFor="let source of sampleKmls">
                {{ source }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h4>Callouts:</h4>
            <div *ngFor="let source of sampleSources">
                {{ source }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h4>LiveFeeds:</h4>
            <div>
                No LiveFeeds
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: There is a useful npm package for this [ngx-clipboard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-clipboard) - allows you to copy source (including new lines, line breaks, etc.), if you cant add any old package to your project, I guess you could just see what they are doing in the source code of this package.

Comment: I would rather not use packages